BillingClient Android: EEA reporting alternative payments to google play
I'm trying to implement "alternative payments" reporting to Google Play as described here
We don't want sell subscriptions/add-ons through Google Play, rather we sell those separately by our own means. However, according to the newest terms we need to report those external transactions to Google Play.
After starting the connection billingClient?.startConnection() and calling:
billingClient?.isAlternativeBillingOnlyAvailableAsync()

I get:
Response Code: BILLING_UNAVAILABLE, 
Debug Message: The developer's billing profile for this billing program was not found

details
Possible reasons are:
The Play Store app on the user's device is out of date.
The user is in an unsupported country.
The user is an enterprise user, and their enterprise admin has disabled users from making purchases.
Google Play is unable to charge the user’s payment method. For example, the user's credit card might have expired.
App namespace is wrong

Any possible ways of approaching this issue? How to isolate the possible reason? What does billing profile for this billing program mean?
